# Can I use OpenCart in Weebly?

Tags: weebly, opencart

I need the iDeal payment method in Weebly. Since they don't offer it, I need to use a third party shopping cart - OpenCart 2.0. Can OpenCart be added to Weebly? I asked at Weebly and OpenCart before asking here.

Comment: you should ask at weebly support...

Comment: I tried Weebly support first but got no reply.  I also tried OpenCart support. I don't believe Weebly provides support for 3rd party shopping cart issues.

Comment: then you can ask to opencart support that does they support weebly?

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to create a database, full access to database structure, FTP access into the server to mitigate files, permissions support (or other utils)...then Yes.

But I would assume the answer is "NO". I suggest just going for traditional hosting. There isnt really an advantage to using these cheesy web builders nowadays....the Open Source counterparts are usually much more robust/secure/flexible and you wont have to hack in workarounds like this to get a simple payment gateway working.

Answer (score 1):

Weebly does not install or allow for any third party software. You could however link to another third party web service site from your Weebly site.